# is this a Begonia Albopicta var. Rosea??? aka Begonia "Tamaya"?

Tags: identification, hybrids, begonia

Is this plant a hybrid begonia? Yes
How can a wax begonia make a cane begonia that then makes a wax begonia?

I have managed to get viable seeds from this angle wing,
Which have germinated and made a semperflorin looking seedlings and a twin pair of a very different type of begonia....as in the photos.
This is my first post any info would be greatly appreciated.[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Begonia does not necessarily come true from seed, so any plants you manage to raise that way may not be named varieties

Comment: Thanks Bamboo, it is amazing how they go back to the original plants but different. I have managed to learn how to make proper begonia bamboo from the "Tamaya" as seen in the last photos. I'm in the process of making more true bamboo style begonia up to 6ft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice photos, the adult plant on the left with the pink flowers - looks like a "cane begonia". The seedling might change their leaves as they grow.

Comment: Thanks :) the photos of the big plants are the same plant. They show the same plant from one original cutting! The one one the left decided to grow like bamboo.